# About the time object is released when it is popped in navigation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Let's see my code:

```
- (void)back {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.text);
}
```

The code is in arc. When the back method is called, the dealloc method is called then. But I have some confusion about it. I know if the `navigationController` pop a object, the object will be released.

So my idea is when the method `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` is called, the dealloc method will be called before method `NSLog(@"%@", self.text);`.

But the actually result is opposite. So I guess when the method `popViewControllerAnimated` is called, the `navigationController` didn't release the object at once, but after some time.

I want't to know if my guess is right. And if so, how it decide when to release the object?

Comment: Does `NSLog(@"%@", self.text);` prints something?

Comment: Yew, it works, prints the string I have defined.